# Regex date format less than operator

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to use regex to verify a date format and I would like to check if the day is less than 32. Similarly, that the month is also less than 12. I have no idea how to about it. Currently, this is what I have;

```
^[0-1]?[0-9]{1}\-[0-3]?[0-9]{1}\-[0-9]{2,4}$
```

This regex achieves the format  (m)m-(d)d-(yy)yy

Comment: what is the date format you wish to match?

Comment: Oh sorry. (m)m-(d)d-(yy)yy. That is the format that the regex above achieves.

Comment: Ok, then please update your question with the details thanks

Comment: I am not sure if a regexp the right approach. Even when it matches, because the day is less than 32 and the month is less or equal than 12, you still might end up with invalid dates: 02/30/16 for example. I think is makes more sense to just try to parse the string with [Date.strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime)

Comment: Regular expressions should generally be used to extract information, not perform comparison operations. Don't inflict self-harm this way.

Comment: I'd recommend using the Date, DateTime or Time classes. A regular expression can get into the ball-park, but will fail if you're dealing with a month that has fewer than 31 days, and/or when February has 29, so you'd still have to have a validity check, which is already built into those classes.

Comment: If the month is February, why would you want to confirm that the day is less than 32? Don't you want to know if the month is less than `13`, not `12`? Ruby's months and days both begin at `1`, not `0`. I am not familiar with the terminology `(m)m-(d)d-(yy)yy`. I suspect you want to know if the string represents a valid date, though the date format may be one among several. If so, say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[0-1][1-2]|[1-9])\-(?:3[0-1]|[0-2][1-9]|[1-9])\-[0-9]{2}(?:[0-9]{2})?$
```

should do what you're looking for. It will only allow months from 1-12 (either 1-9 or 01-12), days from 1-31 (either 1-9 or 01-31) and years of at least 2 digits with a maximum of four. Tested on regex101.

Comment: It sure does. That was intentional. I was debating making it only match 2 or 4 digits, but there have been years with three digits in them in history, so I figured it wouldn't be a dealbreaker to allow it.

Comment: `^` and `$` are beginning and ending of *line* (respectively) in Ruby, not *string*. You almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Don't use regular expressions for comparison operations. Use a regex to split off values to compare, or use an actual parser.

### Use Regular Expressions to Extract Comparables

Date comparisons is a really poor problem for regex to solve. At most, you should use a regular expression to extract your days of the month for a numeric comparison. For example:

```
date = '01-01-1970'
date.split('-')[1].to_i < 32
#=> true
```

However, the code above won't really tell you if a given date is *valid*. For example, what about February 30th or November 31st? Instead, you should attempt to parse the date to determine its validity.

### Use a Date Parser

The best way to tell if a given date is valid is to parse it with a date parser, and then report a Boolean result or handle the exception. For example, you could attempt to parse the date with [Date#parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse).

#### Boolean Results

If you just want a Boolean result, you can coerce a valid/invalid parse to true or false. For example:

```
require 'date'

date = '01-33-1970'
!!(Date.parse date rescue nil)
#=> false
```

#### Rescuing and Reporting the Exception

Less magically, you would need to rescue ArgumentError from [Date#parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse). For example:

```
require 'date'

def valid_date? date_string
  true if Date.parse date_string
rescue ArgumentError => e
  STDERR.puts "#{e.class}: #{e}: '#{date_string}'"
  false
end

valid_date? '11-31-1970'
```

This will do what you expect, albeit more verbosely. For example, the above example will print the exception to standard error, and then return false as the result.

> ArgumentError: invalid date: '11-31-1970'
>      #=> false

Comment: Most definitely use the classes to parse and validate. A regex can't validate: `Date.strptime('02-30-2001', '%m-%d-%Y')  # ~> ArgumentError: invalid date`

Answer (score 0):

## Basic:

Here is a regex that should do what you want:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]|[1-9])-\d{2}(\d{2})?$
```

It matches months greater than 0 and less than 13, then `-`, then days greater than 0 and less than 32, then `-`, then years (2 digits or 4 digits).

## Bonus:

Full regex for matching dates in that format with validation:

```
^((0?[13578]|10|12)-(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))-((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)-(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))-((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$
```

Comment: Your first doesn't match single digits, and the second has wayyyyyy too many capture groups. XD

Comment: @JohnClifford Fixed.  And it works perfectly even if it has too many capture goups...

Comment: I've always operated under the assumption that having a lot of capture groups has a performance overhead. It probably doesn't, to be fair. I eliminate them anywhere I don't need to use the captured values somewhere else, but that's likely just my own quirk so you're quite right.

Comment: `^` and `$` are beginning and ending of *line* (respectively) in Ruby, not *string*. You almost always want `\A` and `\z` instead.

Comment: Technically the second captures the `mm/dd/yyyy` values, but it doesn't validate as it's perfectly happy to accept `02-30-2001`. Maintaining such a pattern is much more difficult than using `Date.strptime('02-30-2001', '%m-%d-%Y')  # ~> ArgumentError: invalid date` which will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine the string is a valid date, you'd be better off attempting to convert it. If it won't convert, it's not valid.

```
def date_valid?(date_string)
  format = '%m/%d/' + (date_string.split(-).last.size == 4 ? '%Y' : '%y')
  return true if Date.strptime(date_string, format)
  rescue ArgumentError
  return false
end
```